# IF NULL SQL returning error

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I want a SQL query to return "VIDE" when the field is empty in Sales Cloud but I have an error message saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Here is my SQL part : 
IF NULL (Code_Provenance__c, 'VIDE') as 'CODE_PROVENANCE',

Comment: I have founded a solution to my problem using CASE function.

Comment: Please either provide your solution as an accepted answer, or remove the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to resolve this (I know you mentioned in your comments that you utilized CASE to solve for it, but thought i should leave something as a reference for anyone else having this issue):

1. CASE statements:

```sql
SELECT primarykey,
CASE
  WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN
    'Default Value'
  ELSE 
    field1
END as field1
FROM [myDE]
```

2. ISNULL

```sql
SELECT primarykey,
ISNULL(field1,'Default Value') as field1
FROM [myDE]
```

3. COALESCE

```sql
SELECT primarykey,
COALESCE(field1,'Default Value') as field1
FROM [myDE]
```

There may be a couple other ways to accomplish this, but these are three should handle most if not all use cases you may have.

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment, really helpful.